# Debugging MySQL performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance

I work on a WordPress site that gets roughly 100K page views per day. We use Varnish for a caching layer.  Recently, we've been running into a problem where, seemingly at random, MySQL performance slows to a halt and brings down our application.  Here's a graph from New Relic for an outage that occurred yesterday:

[image: Application performance graph]

This has happened twice in the past week.  The site will run fine for a week without anybody touching the production servers, and then this happens out of nowhere.  Usual response time is around 500ms, and here it is peaking at 60K ms(!).  The problem is fixed by stopping apache, letting the database cool down, and then starting apache back up.

It's not that more queries are being run, or that a particular slow query is running and causing this problem.  If I take any of the 'slow queries' that are being reported by New Relic and run them any other time, they are blazing fast.  Here's a graph for MySQL throughput for the same time frame:

[image: Database throughput graph]

I've checked the stats for WordPress hooks and plugins, and everything seems to be normal.

My question is, where should I start looking? Which MySQL settings could be causing this? Is it even likely a MySQL problem, or is it more likely to be an application problem?

Comment: Does it have enough CPU?

Comment: Sysadmins or DBAs would be in  lot better position to answer these questions. Developers come into the play if you manage to identify a piece of code that causes the issue and you want to get it fixed.

Comment: if it's at complete random intervals, i'd check the storage backend. if it's at regular intervals, i'd check for any cronjobs, backup jobs or whatever. in either case, i'd rather ask on server fault, since this is in no way a *coding* question

Comment: Set `long_query_time = 1`; turn on the slowlog; wait a day; summarize the slowlog; then come back for further discussion.  Bring with you the worst query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved.  Sometimes the answer is a simple addition of a composite index to a certain table.

Answer (score 0):

With such a high-traffic site, and since you mentioned varnish, I am presuming you have a VPS/cloud/dedicated hosting, with a linux distro and ssh (root) access.

This being the case, one of the first things you should start checking is the server error logs (the location of which would vary based on the OS you're using - you can google it in case needed). That could give you a hint about the origin of the problem. Checking the top load ( `# top` ) during the outage could also help.

For mysql config/performance tuning and optimization, you can try the following:

1. Install the mtop utility and run it
2. Try this handy tool:

http://mysqltuner.com/

Install and let it run for > 24 hours. Then, it will give you specific recommendations to tune up the mysql config based on your server's mysql usage patterns.